# Correct way to write async / await services in ServiceStack

Tags: c#, asynchronous, servicestack

I m trying to write an async service with ServiceStack and to me it seems that this feature is not really complete.

My questions:

1) How do you pass `CancellationTokens` in the service methods?

2) What about `ConfigureAwait(false)` in those methods? For example

```
public Task<SomeResponse> Get(SomeRequest request)
        {
            return _manager.ExecuteAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
```

This doesnt compile.

3) Should we be marking such services with the async keyword and return Task to make them awaitable? For example this doesnt work (usage is silly but you get the point)

```
public async Task<SomeResponse> Get(SomeRequest request)
        {
            return await _manager.ExecuteAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
```

Should we even be writing async services with ServiceStack? Is there a benefit or the current implementation defeats the purpose?

Thanks

Comment: Side note: usage of `ConfigureAwait` in server code likely brings more troubles than benefits, but it is up to you to learn how particular framework configures synchronization context for async calls and what are outcomes of not restoring thread context when using `ConfigureAwait(false)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If the methods don't accept cancellation tokens, then they weren't designed to be cancellable, and you can't cancel them.
2. You're not actually awaiting the task, so there's no `await` to configure.  Just omit the `ConfigureAwait` since you have no `await` to configure.
3. There's no need to mark a method as `async` if you're not actually going to leverage any of the features of it or accomplish anything with it that isn't already done by just not doing that.  It's not *breaking* anything other than making the code a tiny bit slower, but it's not adding anything either.

Answer (score 1):

You can [make an async request](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/C%23-client#using-the-new-api) as normal using C# async/await, i.e:

```
var response = await client.GetAsync(requestDto);
```

Or if you prefer (or cannot use await), you can use Continuations on the returned `Task<T>`, e.g:

```
client.GetAsync(new Hello { Name = "World!" })
    .Success(r => r => r.Result.Print())
    .Error(ex => { throw ex; });
```

You can cancel an async request with:

```
client.CancelAsync();
```

This calls [HttpWebRequest.Abort()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.abort(v=vs.110).aspx) behind the scenes.